# How do I share Neo4j graphs with Non-technical users?

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j visualizations are fantastic but when I share it with non technical users they get confused. Is there any way to have a version of the portal with just the nodes view, along with some prebuild cypher queries they can click, or maybe even parameterized queries where they don't see the cypher.

I feel like Neo4j has a very powerful user interface but it's only accessible to developers. I'm sure they can click the cypher queries in the star'ed queries section but I'd like to hide them from any code as it may confuse them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user with only the READ privilege

Then, set up custom "cards" available via a :play http://yourdomain/yourcards.html with the content and queries you'll write for your users

Answer (score 1):

For custom browser guides please have a look at the developer page, this should help you create slides for you users that guide them through your data.

http://localhost:8000/developer/resources/guide-create-neo4j-browser-guide/